# Override default rest action in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I created rest api in yii2 for the users. I can access list of users like this "api/web/v1/users" but the problem is that it is giving the data of all the columns including password, I saw in yii2 documentation that it is internally calling **"user/index"** method, is there any way to override the **index** method like this?

```
 class UserController extends ActiveController {
 public $modelClass = 'common\models\User';
        public function actionIndex(){
        //return selected columns here of the user table
        }
}
```

It still gives the list of all users with all columns that I don't want. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you must use `fields()` method and override this method. As Yii defines `fields()`:

> By overriding [[yii\base\Model::fields()|fields()]] and/or [[yii\base\Model::extraFields()|extraFields()]], you may specify what data, called fields, in the resource can be put into its array representation.You can override fields() to add, remove, rename or redefine fields

For example:

```
public function fields()
{
    return [    
        'id','name','username'
    ];
}
```

Above method, tells yii that only show `id`,`name`,`username` fields. So, Password will never be sent to client.

In cases that you want only remove one or more specific fields, you can do like below:

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields=parent::fields();
    unset($fields['password']);
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: In your answer how can you assign `$fields['password']` to something else like `$fields['password']= 1234455`?

Comment: @ovicko, that is not really the point of the fields() method. That method returns an array of field names that the object should expose to bulk output requests like Json::encode() or REST response data. If you wanted to control the value and a set a default or something like you are showing, you would want to do that in the action code or somewhere else in the model itself... or potentially even the view if it is strickly for display. Regardless, fields() shouldn't be used to work with data in any way. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer does work and is an important method to know for basic control of what fields are shared via rest and general "object exporting" functions like Json::encode(), I feel it is important to also understand how to completely override an action like the OP references.

I've answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50744982/3337682, and I feel it would be helpful, added information for the OP.

Hope this helps someone!

~ Cheers :)