# how to override a yii2 rest api generic view method?

Tags: rest, yii2

I am trying to override the default yii2 rest api functions. Particularly the view function. My objective is to filter some of the attributes that I am sending back.
I tried to do a
`unset($actions['view']);` in the `actions()` function of the controller and then defining my own `actionView` method but the call never arrives at this function and always goes to the default method.

My question is specifically regarding the actionView method.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 Override generic create Action in Rest ActiveController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648504/yii2-override-generic-create-action-in-rest-activecontroller)

Comment: @Ali MasudianPour, The unset call and defining the action method doesn't work in my case. Please read the statement

Comment: you should use the model to do that. Also accept answers on your questions.

Comment: What do you mean by **you should use the model to do that** 
And how to accept answers on questions?
Sorry for being a noob. I am new at this.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to override the actionView method. Instead overriding the actionIndex method solved the problem. Now the get call reaches my function.

I am not certain whether this is the correct solution to address the issue but it solves the problem for now. For some reason the actionView method does not get called. It might be the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
class CountryController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Country';

    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['create']);
        return $actions;
    }

    public function actionCreate(){
        // implement here your code
    }
}
```

Refer : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648504/yii2-override-generic-create-action-in-rest-activecontroller)